# Using IMAP to Read Emails

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I am having a pretty frustrating issue here. I have been playing around, attempting to make a script that could read emails from an IMAP email server (notably gmail) to no avail. Is there no way to do this anymore? Every code I've looked at online and attempted to implement failed me. I manage emails for inmates who are incarcerated, and now I have to login to every email to check for new messages, when I'd love to just have a script that could grab the messages and shove them in a database. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show the script you have tried

Comment: $mailboxes = array(
 array(
  'label'  => 'Gmail',
  'enable' => true,
  'mailbox'  => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
  'username'  => 'inmate.scribes1@gmail.com',
  'password'  => 'customer123'
 ),

);

if ($pageauth['username'] && $pageauth['password']) {
 if(($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]!==$pageauth['username']) || ( $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"]!==$pageauth['password'])){
  header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=Protected area" );
  header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
  echo "Protected area";
  exit;
 }
}

Comment: That's the imap call at least, wouldn't let me past the whole script.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you've tried so that people can help you easily

Comment: What is your code and what is your error? Please update your question.